# Android studio compiler error build tools

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I receive the following error message

```
Could not initialize class com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler
```

How do I solve this error message, I honestly have no idea how to solve this error message ?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe update the following code in the build.gradle(project) file?

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        [some other things here...]
    }
    dependencies {
        [.... some other things here]
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
    }
}
```